# Query to show only related workitems based on filter criteria

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a query in Azure DevOps to meet the following criteria.  It will be used in a tile on a dashboard.

[image: VSTS Workitem Linkage]

I want to see a subset of workitems in Area B (owned by another team), however the tags, states and statuses don't match my team's needs.  Additionally, due to frequent changes to process in Area B, reliable static queries are difficult.

I want to use workitems in Area A (owned by my team) to manage tags, states and statuses in order to create reliable static queries, then present the workitems in Area B in the final list.

My approach will be to relate an item in Area A (relates to) an item in Area B.  Area A items will always have only 1 related item in Area B.  Then filter Area A items, and the query ONLY return Area B items.

Is this possible in Azure DevOps?  Is there a better way to accomplish the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I created 4 items in areaA, three of which are children of item200.
[image]
Associate each child item in areaA with one item in areaB.
[image] 
Select **Work items and direct links** in the query. The filter conditions are as shown below. You can get the list of items in the areaA related to the items in the areaB.
However, the items in areaB cannot be listed separately.
[image]